# Comparision between date and integer in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have dataset df with date column. I have dates from 2020-01-01 to 2021-03-30 in date column. Now i have a variable like a=20210130(which is actually a date). I need take take values from the df which is <=a.

Answer (score 0):

First idea is convert `a` to datetimes and compare, then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

a = 20210130
df = df[df['date'] <= pd.to_datetime(a)]
```

Or convert column to integers and compare:

```
a = 20210130
df = df[df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int) <= a]
```